# onclick for created Id, does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello people here is my code below...

```
            #ajax code after success
            $.each(obj,function(index,Object) {
                ban_list += '<div class="ban_n" id='+Object.To+'>remove ban</div>';

            })

        $('.b_list').html(ban_list).toString();
```

above code works fine by creating a div with the `class=ban_n` and `id=get1_name` `get1_name is nothing but Object.To` now i have to set onclick for `ban_n`

```
$('.ban_n').on('click',function(){
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

why is the above code does not work.. anyway to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation method since you have dynamically added that div:

```
$(document).on('click','.ban_n',function(){
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

[learn more about event delegation here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `delegation`

```
$('.b_list').on('click','.ban_n',function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
})
```